# How to use Atmega1284AU with Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, bootloader

Is there any support to this chip in Arduino IDE, like bootloaders and boards definitions.. i want to use this chip with 3.3V and 8Mhz crystal speed..

I have seen Nick Gammon bootloaders supports this chip for bootloaders, but not with 8Mhz.? and how to add this chip to Arduino IDE.

anybody help..

thanks you

Answer (score 1):

Please check out MightyCore library by MCUdude.

https://github.com/MCUdude/MightyCore

I have used it and can verify it works pretty well with ATmega1284.